# How do you loop through two separate lists of columns within single dataframe to create multiple tables in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am struggling to figure out how to use purr::map2 to create multiple tables using two different lists of columns within a dataframe. The purpose is twofold: 1) determine how the columns are different.

Below is a toy example dataframe I'm working with (the actual dataframe has close to 300 columns, of which I am interested in comparing 100 pairs, i.e. 200.

```
df = data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(2,3,8), a1 = c(1, 2, 3), b1 = c(2, 3, 9))

   a b   a1 b1   ….
1  1 2    1  2
2  2 3    2  3
3  3 8    3  9
```

I realize there are multiple ways of going about achieving my task. As I said, my initial idea was to iterate over multiple columns using purr and then creating a list of tables.

```
names1 <- c("a", "b")
names2 <- c("a1", "b2")

df %>% purr::map2(~table(.$names1, .$names2, useNA = "always))
```

I would expect a list that looks something like the code below.

```
       1 2 3 <NA>            
  1    1 0 0    0
  2    0 1 0    0
  3    0 0 1    0
  <NA> 0 0 0    0


       2 3 9 <NA>
  2    1 0 0    0
  3    0 1 0    0
  8    0 0 1    0
  <NA> 0 0 0    0
```

Instead I get the following error:

```
Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: If you're doing a bunch of tasks with this data, you may want to consider using `tidyr::gather()` first. Then you'll be able to do things like select and filter more easily on the different data fields. It might help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(2,3,8), a1 = c(1, 2, 3), b1 = c(2, 3, 9))
names1 <- c("a", "b")
names2 <- c("a1", "b1")

purrr::map2(names1, names2, ~table(df[[.x]], df[[.y]], useNA = "always"))
#> [[1]]
#>       
#>        1 2 3 <NA>
#>   1    1 0 0    0
#>   2    0 1 0    0
#>   3    0 0 1    0
#>   <NA> 0 0 0    0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>       
#>        2 3 9 <NA>
#>   2    1 0 0    0
#>   3    0 1 0    0
#>   8    0 0 1    0
#>   <NA> 0 0 0    0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>